# select rows in sql with latest date for each ID repeated multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have a table where each ID is repeated 3 times. there is a date in front of each id in each row.
I want to select entire row for each ID where date is latest. 
There are total 370 columns in this table i want all columns to get selected when i select that row.

Sample -

```
ID   Name    Date        Marks    ..    ..  ..   
1     XY     4/3/2017     27
1     fv     4/3/2014     98
1     jk     4/3/2016     09
2     RF     4/12/2015    87
2     kk     4/3/2009     56
2     PP     4/3/2011     76
3     ee     4/3/2001     12
3     ppp    4/3/2003     09
3     lll    4/3/2011     23
```

The Answer should be

```
ID   Name    Date        Marks    ..    ..  ..   
1     XY     4/3/2017     27      
2     RF     4/12/2015    87
3     lll    4/3/2011     23
```

I am attempting as below -

```
select distinct ID,*,max(date) as maxdate from table
```

Also i am trying this in Hive . so not sure if some sql functions dont work in Hive

Thanks

Comment: similar question has been answered here-
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523049/hive-sql-find-the-latest-record/43528852#43528852

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This question has been asked before. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql) question.

Using the accepted answer and adapting it to your problem you get:

```
SELECT tt.*
FROM myTable tt
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ID, MAX(Date) AS MaxDateTime
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY ID) groupedtt 
ON tt.ID = groupedtt.ID 
AND tt.Date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime
```

Comment: looks like in the last line it  should be  AND tt.Date = groupedtt.MaxDateTime  .... Thanks

Comment: Sure thing. If you liked the answer please upvote and select as the accepted answer.

Comment: what if date comes from user and same or prevoius dates come???

Answer (score 9):

One way is:

```
select table.* 
from table
join 
(
    select ID, max(Date) as max_dt 
    from table
    group by ID
) t
on table.ID= t.ID and table.Date = t.max_dt
```

Note that if you have multiple equally higher dates for same ID, then you will get all those rows in result

Comment: yes ..exactly thats' how it is happening ... then i think i can just remove the duplicate rows from entire database ... then those multiple rows will go away and for each id there will be only one row.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a Correlated Subquery (That is a subquery wherein you reference a field in the main query). In this case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from yourtable WHERE id = t1.id)
```

Here we give the `yourtable` table an alias of `t1` and then use that alias in the subquery grabbing the `max(date)` from the same table `yourtable` for that `id`.

Comment: this is a very slow way to do that.

Comment: @MaksimKniazev I disagree. MySQL's execution plan will be similar to the explicit INNER JOIN on an aggregated subquery in this case.

Comment: Takes forever when the data is huge.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a join to do this

```
SELECT t1.* from myTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN myTable t2 on t2.ID=t1.ID AND t2.`Date` > t1.`Date`
WHERE t2.`Date` IS NULL;
```

Only rows which have the latest date for each ID with have a NULL join to t2.

Comment: Old school. Nice.

Comment: This is giving me error as Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'date'

Comment: Is that the error mysql is reporting? I don't know if its the problem but Date is a reserver word so I've updated my answer with backticks.

Comment: I think that's a HIVE error - My code is intended for MySql

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN is synonym to LEFT JOIN, its clearer that way I think to use the simpler terms...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  The inner query gets the max date for each id.  Then you can join that back to your main table to get the rows that match.

```
select
*
from
<your table>
inner join 
(select id, max(<date col> as max_date) m
where yourtable.id = m.id
and yourtable.datecolumn = m.max_date)
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*), max(date)
FROM table 
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: This will not return all of the fields in the table for the record with that id that has the max date.